# Improper Routing when deploying Node.js app to Render VPS

Tags: node.js, express, url, routes

I am deploying a Node.js Express app to a VPS by Render.  When I run the app on my local machine, the npm start command does a great job of serving my file when I point the browser to localhost:3001.  However, after I deploy, the base directory '/' returns "Not found".  I have to point my browser to example.onrender.com/public/index.html.

How do I make sure that example.onrender.com/ routes the request to public/index.html?

Thank you!

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});


app.listen(3001);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually just had to change "Publish Directory" settings in Render to ./public